# VSIX and VS SHELL : problems with window show()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, modal-dialog, vsix, vspackage

If I make non-modal window I get different problems. Firts of all I open the Experimental version of Visual Studio and open a Solution where I navigate to a C# page. Then I open my Extension's WPF window where I can happily type into TextBoxes in that WPF window. However, whenever I click the backspace [<-] or the [delete] keys, this doesn't affect the current WPF textbox but the previously opened C# code window in the current solution.  I open my window in this way:

```
 window = new MyWindow()
 window.show();
```

I know that I could resolve my problem  with :

```
 uiShell.EnableModeless(0);
 window = new MyWindow()
 window.ShowDialog();
 uiShell.EnableModeless(1);
```

But I don't want this solution. I want to navigate file in visual studio shell and at the same time using my addin without having problem with input. How Can I resolve this problem using Show() ?

Comment: You should inherit from DialogWindow

Comment: Does my Window should inherit from DialogWindow and Should I use Window.Show() ?

Comment: Ok I inherit from DialogWindow. But with Show() I have the same problem. 
I open my addin, I write in a textbox, then I click on vs shell (c# file): If I delete on my textbox the cursor remains on c# file

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275337/visual-studio-editor-window-stealing-focus

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a "non-modal" window, it needs to be a toolwindow, or a document window. Otherwise, VS will not know about it, and you'll encounter all sorts of problems with it not getting messages, events, accelerators, etc...

If you want a modal window, use the DialogWindow class as previously mentioned to ensure the IDE can properly disable/enable it's windows when the dialog is displayed or dismissed.

Sincerely,